# Validating SQL query with PHP

Tags: php, sql, validation, postgresql

The validation seems to fail for some reason. By the validation, I mean the "`if ($result)`" -part. How can I correctly validate SQL-query?

```
$dbconn = pg_connect("host=localhost port=5432 dbname=heoa user=heoa password=123");
$email  = $_POST['login']['email'];

$result = pg_query_params( $dbconn,
                'SELECT user_id
                FROM users
                WHERE email = $1',
                array( $email )
                );
if ($result)
{
        while ( $row = pg_fetch_array( $result ) )
        {
                $user_id = $row['user_id'];
        }
        return $user_id;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that the return value is integer zero which is also interprested as false in the if statement. By doing "if ($result !== FALSE)" (Note that it should be !== and ***not*** !=) you'll verify if the result really is different than FALSEand not just false...

Comment: This can't be correct because per documentation, `pg_query_params` returns _A query result resource on success or FALSE on failure_.  This code is correct except that it should call `pg_last_error()` to know why the db failed on that query.

Answer (score 0):

Should you add apostraphe's around $1 in your SQL query, as in?

```
SELECT user_id
FROM users
WHERE email = '$1'
```

I'm not sure how PHP expands the $1 variable.

Comment: (a) PHP doesn't expand variables in single-quoted strings.  (b) Using the `$1` parameters is correct usage in the `pg` API.  (c) Don't put query parameters in quotes, because they'll be interpreted as literal strings in the SQL expression, instead of parameters.

Comment: thanks, I wasn't sure.  I haven't coded PHP pages in at least five years so the rust is pretty thick if you get my gist